# A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 32, 32, 256), (None, 16, 16, 256)]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a U-Net model for 256x256 nifti-1 file for my biomedical project on Kaggle. I got things perfectly when I used 128x128. I am getting an error I don't know what is the problem please help me to resolve this.

```
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_CHANNELS))
s = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x / 255)(inputs)

#Contraction path
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(s)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c1)
c1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c1)
p1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c1)

c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p1)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c2)
c2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c2)
p2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c2)
 
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p2)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c3)
c3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c3)
p3 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(c3)
 
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p3)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c4)
c4 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c4)
p4 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)
 
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p4)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c5)
c5 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c5)
p5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c4)

c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(p5)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(c6)
c6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c6)
#Expansive path 
u7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c6)
```

**!!!!error in this line**

```
u7 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u7, c5])
```

```
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c7)
c7 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c7)

u8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c7)
u8 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u8, c4])
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c8)
c8 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c8)
 
u9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c8)
u9 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u9, c3])
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(c9)
c9 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c9)
 
u10 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c9)
u10 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u10, c2])
c10 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u10)
c10 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c10)
c10 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c10)
 
u11 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same')(c10)
u11 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([u11, c1], axis=3)
c11 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(u11)
c11 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(c11)
c11 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same')(c11)
```

Comment: `p5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo where you're defining the Max Pool 2D for `p5`. Please do:

```
p5 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(c5)
```